# C# Как повысить производительность консольного приложения?

Tags: c#

НЕ говорите про "правильный" код и прочее.

В моей нужде выполняются примитивные вычислительные операции, но с каждый проходом их количество увеличивается вдвое. Что-то вроде брут-форса.

По диспетчеру задач, моё приложение в независимо от проведённого времени потребляет 15% ЦПУ. При таких условиях выполнить вычисления проблематично.

Можно ли как-нибудь поднять предел использования ЦПУ? Чтоб допустим использовалось 50 или 75% ?

Comment: А как нам "НЕ говорить про "правильный" код", если он у вас не правильный, ибо вы явно не используете асинхронность, многопоточность и другие приблуды.  Добавляйте код с проблемным участком и будем смотреть что с ним не так, сейчас же ваш вопрос бессмыслен как для нас, так и для вас.

Comment: `НЕ говорите про "правильный" код и прочее` Если ваш код не может в многопоточность, то он так и будет грузить только одно ядро процессора, и будет с одинаковой скоростью работать как на i3, так и на i9 (плюс-минус). Так что ваш код - неправильный чтобы грузить проц хотя бы на 50-75%.

Answer (score 2):

Этот вопрос не относится к языку программирования никак. Видимо, у вас 6 ядер, и вы пишете программу в одном потоке. Соответственно, ограничение в 15% это максимум, который вы сможете получить. Распараллельте вашу задачу, тогда сможете увеличить нагрузку ЦПУ за счёт использования большего числа ядер.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.